# Try to use $pull but get error "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
"_id": "608ab562870b912adac9c410",
 "drt": {
       "templates": [{
            "shop_template_id": "6092923793bcfa950d05a3d5",
            "created_at": "2021-05-05T19:19:12.689Z",
            "template_name": "V28",
            "content": "aaa"
          }]
     }
}
```

And something gets wrong when I try to remove it with the following query:

```
db
.collection('books')
.updateMany(
    { _id: new ObjectID(id)},
    { $pull: {drt: {templates: {shop_template_id: new ObjectID(templateId)}}}},
    { multi: true }
)
```

I get this error message: `"Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"`

What I'm do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dot notation for nested field:

```
{
    $pull: {
        "drt.templates": {
            shop_template_id: ObjectId("6092923793bcfa950d05a3d5")
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1ShYDF56g_)

Comment: Thanks dude, I did not notice it!! 
Now It works perfect!